# How to make repeating notifications with different content

Tags: java, android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I need to show repeating notifications to the user with different content.  I use BroadcastReceiver and set notifications via AlarmManager.

I know that I can use `AlarmManager.setRepeating`, but it shows the same content every time.

For example, I need to show notifications one time a week depending on the selected week by the user. And in every notification, I need to show current Week and some different text. I didn't find a solution on StackOverflow.

Here is the relevant code

```
long timeInMills = mSharedPreferences.getLong("key_millis", 0);

Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMills);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

int currentWeek = (int) Utils.getTotalWeeks(timeInMills);

if (currentWeek <= 20) {
    AlarmHelper alarmHelper = AlarmHelper.getInstance();
    for (int i = currentWeek + 1; i < 21; i++) {
        alarmCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7 * (currentWeek + 1));
        long time = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmHelper.setWeekAlarm(getApplicationContext(), WeekReceiver.class, time, i, i);
    }
}
```

And the `AlarmHelper` class is the following.

```
public class AlarmHelper {

    private static AlarmHelper instance;

    public static AlarmHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AlarmHelper();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void setWeekAlarm(Context context, Class<?> receiver, long time, int week, int req_code) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiver);
        intent.putExtra("week_title", "your week " + week);
        intent.putExtra("req_code", req_code);

        //cancel already existed alarm
        cancelWeekAlarm(context, receiver, req_code);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, req_code, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void cancelWeekAlarm(Context context, Class<?> receiver, int req_code) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiver);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, req_code, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the user is on the first week, so 20 notifications will be created and I think my approach is not very good and maybe you can help me find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what is the purpose of your code, as I did not understand the question clearly. However, I think I found a problem in your code which I think I should share.

While you are adding a `Calendar` event, I think you are trying to add weeks incrementally in different weeks. However, in your code looks like you are setting all the events in a certain week.

I am referring to the following code. Please see the comments in the code.

```
if (currentWeek <= 20) {
    AlarmHelper alarmHelper = AlarmHelper.getInstance();
    for (int i = currentWeek + 1; i < 21; i++) {

        // I think the following line should contain currentWeek + i instead of currentWeek + 1
        // alarmCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7 * (currentWeek + 1)); 

        alarmCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7 * (currentWeek + i)); // Like this to create events in consecutive weeks.

        long time = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmHelper.setWeekAlarm(getApplicationContext(), WeekReceiver.class, time, i, i);
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: My code works completely. In code i miss current week and start notifications from the next week.

Comment: Do you think this is because you are not adding the current week in the loop? Because the loop starts from currentweek + 1?

Comment: I'm confused. I don't remember why i used (Calendar.Date, 7 * (currentWeek + 1)); instead simple (Calendar.Date, 7); Thank.. I will check it.

Comment: No problem. I hope you will find the problem. Let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: Great to know that helped! Have a great day!